# How can I limit the number of integers input?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that will ask the user to input 25 integers.

This is where I'm at now:

```
while True:
    numbers = list(map(int, input("Enter 25 numbers (seperate it with space): ").split()))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you know how to check the length of a list? If you check the length of `numbers` afterward, can you use that to solve the problem? What actually is the difficulty?

Comment: Combine Karl Knechtel's comment with [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/354577)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. It will prompt you with the question again if you do not enter the right amount of characters. Plus, it does not count spaces as characters.

```
gettingInput = True

while gettingInput:
    numbers = list(map(int, input("Enter 25 numbers (seperate it with space): ").split()))
    if len(numbers) - numbers.count(" ") > 25:
        gettingInput = True
    else:
        gettingInput = False
# (- numbers.count(" ") will not count spaces as characters.)
```